# Unit Testing private functions in AngularJS Directive

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How do I unit test a function that is defined inside a directive like the following `myFunc`?

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('myDir', [function () {

    var myFunc = function (arg) {
      // code in here.
    };

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: { },
      link: function (scope, element) {

      }
    };
  }]);
```

Or how do you define testable directive specific functions that I don't want to expose outside of the directive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most common approach is to not test private methods, but instead test the public interfaces that expose their behaviour. This means that your unit test becomes a contract for your public interface.

You've stated that you don't want to expose outside of the directive but of course the other option is to extract this logic into some service `myDirService` and perform your logic there. In that case you'll be able to test in isolation.

Comment: I only referred to this method because I was unable to simulate an event with the proper values. I know an e2e test would be probably best to test this but I wanted to also have some unit tests for it. The event that I was trying to simulate was ```change``` event on a file input. My directive was listening to that and I was not able to get the event object have the proper target and files on it. I think I should just ask this in a separate question though, Thanks for the explaination.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @eddiec, ideally we shouldn't be in a situation where we need to test private methods, but we don't live in an ideal world.

The way I've found that works is by putting all private vars inside a private object - say `model` and then have a getter function to access any of it's properties. The scope is accessible from any jasmine test once you compile the directive.

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDir', [function() {

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {

    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
        var model = {
            myPrivateVar: 'myValue'
        };

        model.myPrivateFunction = function(arg) {
            // work with arg
        };

        scope.getVal = function(prop, args) {
            // Getter function to access any private variables
            if (model.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                // If the requested var exists, return it.
                return args ? model[prop](args) : model[prop];
            }
            return null;
        };

    }
};
}]);
```

I'm still not super happy with this solution, but it works for now.